# SonarQube :timeLine with versions

Tags: sonarqube

In SonarQube, how can I produce a TimeLine with versions (instead of dates) of project on the x axis, like this:

[image: TimeLine Mock Up]

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: In sonarQube , the timline by default is based on dates, do you know: plugins, widgets or a trick to produce a timeline with versions of project instead dates (evolution of  metrics from version1 to version n)